# Vector of object pointers containing vectors end up pointing to same object

Tags: c++

I am storing multiple objects in a vector of pointers to these objects, like so, in C++:

```
vector<Host *> somevector;
```

I then initialize each item like this:

```
somevector.push_back(new Host(x));
```

The object takes an initializing argument.
As I read through data (strings) and end up with a list of object pointers, I add them to an internal vector inside the object itself:

```
somevector.at(i)->add(string data);
```

However, it appears that all the data have been added to the same object, and even though the objects have different names, their internal vector that stores this data are identical.

I searched various keywords to solve this and I think it is an issue with a copy constructor (I currently am using default). How do I account for the vector inside the object that I am copying? Do I have to make the vector in the object a field so that a new one is created in the copy constructor?

EDIT:

I've replicated the code for the object class:

```
vector<string> v;

Host::Host(string _x): x(_x)
{
}

Host::~Host()
{
}

string Host::name()
{
  return x;
}

string Host::link(int r)
{
  int i = r % v.size();
  return v.at(i);
}

void Host::add(string data)
{
  v.push_back(data);
}
```

So I am using this vector inside the host object to store a bunch of strings. Then, when I call link from my main program, I pass it a random number, and I want to get a random string from the list inside the object. However, my link() calls are coming back with strings that should not have been stored into the object.

Comment: You should show us the actual code - with the information you give us, we can only guess.

Comment: Is "data" a pointer? Are you forgetting to new it each time you modify it, thus meaning you change the data of everything that points at it?

Comment: Without seeing the code for `object`, it's impossible to know, but you almost certainly should not be using a raw pointer.

Comment: Some hints: instead of using `somelist.at(i)`, you could just use `somelist[i]`. Also, this seems like an ideal scenario for the use of a [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Comment: I have edited with the code for the object. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Nordak: Is this real code? Because then the problem would be that `v` is a global variable, and thus shared by all instances of `Host`. If you want it to be a member variable, you have to move the declaration into the class declaration.

Comment: Watch out; `somelist.push_back(new object(x))` is not exception-safe and may introduce a memory leak (when `new` succeeds but `push_back` throws an exception).

Comment: There are some terribly-named variables here. `somelist` is not a `list`, it's a `std::vector` (of pointers to either `object` or `Host`, it's not entirely clear from the way this question is worded). As it stands, it's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Sorry, I have replaced the strange words to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see from the example code you have posted 'v' isn't a member object of Host. So calls to Host::add are simply pushing back to a globally available vector. Is this perhaps where your problem is?

Comment: This appears to be the problem; I want the vector v to be a vector accessible to both link() and add() though; how will I be able to do this without making v global within the file?

Comment: @Nordak: You will want to make `v` a member variable of the class `Host`. Then each `Host` will have its own copy.

Comment: An interface like the following will allow add and link to talk to the same 'v' while maintaining a separate 'v' for each instance of Host.
`class Host
{

private:
   vector<string> v;
   const string x;

public:
   Host(string _x): x(_x){};
   ~Host(){};
   string name();
   link(int r);
   add(string s);
};`